# How can the CDF always be a uniform distribution if some values are more likely than others?

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

I can prove symbolically that given some random variable $X$ with a strictly increasing continuous CDF, $F$ that $Y = F(X)$ has a Uniform(0,1) distribution:

$$P(Y \leq y) = P(F(X) \leq y) = P(X \leq F^{-1}(y)) = F(F^{-1}(y)) = y$$

But I can't reconcile this with my intuition from looking at the plot of a PDF:

[image]

This PDF tells us that values around $x=a$ are less common than values around $x=b$. Values around $x=b$ will also correspond to higher values of the CDF. If we're more likely to plug $x=b$ into $F$ than $x=a$, then shouldn't $Y = F(X)$ not be uniform? Shouldn't $Y$ take on values around $F(b)$ more often than it takes on values around $F(a)$?

Comment: What you call a 'symbolic' proof is the usual analytical proof.

Comment: @StubbornAtom: I agree. My question is why looking at the question from a different perspective arrives at a different answer (clearly something about my thinking is flawed but I don't know what yet).

Answer (score 1):

From the start, I think you may be mixing up the CDF with the inverse CDF (also called the quantile function).

Suppose $X \sim \mathsf{Beta}(2,1),$ so that the density function is
$f_X(x) = 2x,$ for $0 < x < 1$ (and $0$ otherwise). Then the CDF is
$F_X(x) = x^2,$ for $0 < x < 1.$

Now let $U \sim \mathsf{UNIF}(0,1)$ and set $U = F_X(X)$ so that
$F_X^{-1}(U) = \sqrt{U} = X.$  This result is widely used in simulation to
sample realizations of $X.$  If one generates a random sample from $\mathsf{UNIF}(0,1)$ and takes square roots of the values, then one
has a random sample from $\mathsf{Beta}(2,1).$

Here are histograms 20,000 realizations of $U \sim \mathsf{Unif}(0,1)$ and corresponding
$X = \sqrt{U}  \sim \mathsf{Beta}(2,1).$ Colors of objects and images are the same. Each histogram bar represents about 2000 values.

[image]

```
u = runif(20000);  x = sqrt(u)
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
 cutp.u = seq(0, 1, by=.1)
 hist(u, prob=T, ylim=c(0,2), br=cutp.u, col=rainbow(12), main="UNIF(0,1)")
  curve(dunif(x), add=T, n=10001, lwd=2)
 cutp.x = sqrt(cutp.u)
 hist(x, prob=T, ylim=c(0,2), br=cutp.x, col=rainbow(12), main="BETA(2,1)")
  curve(dbeta(x,2,1), add=T, n=10001, lwd=2)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

Answer (score 1):

You're forgetting the chain rule. If $X=g(Y)$, $Y$ has pdf $f(g(y))|g'(y)|$, whose graph differs in shape from that of $f$ due to the $g'$ factor. When $g=F^{-1}$, this exactly cancels the $f$-dependence.

Comment: You mean _functional_ dependence, right?

Comment: No, the proportionality to $f$.

Comment: are you still letting that $Y=F(X)$? I'm assuming not because then X and Y would be defined in terms of each other...

Comment: also do you mean that X has that PDF?

Answer (score 1):

This might help with the intuition ...

[image: the action of F on X]

Consider $Y=F(X)$ where $F$ is the CDF of $X$, i.e. $F(x)=P(X\le x)$. The action of $F$ on $X$ can be seen as moving the probability distributed on the $x$-axis and re-distributing it on the $y$-axis. Notice that as it does so, if $A$ and $B$ are *equal*-length $x$-intervals with $P(X\in A)<P(X\in B)$, then $A$ gets mapped into a *shorter* interval than does $B$ -- i.e., the re-distribution spreads out the probability on the $y$-axis more just where it's more concentrated on the $x$-axis. An analytical proof shows that in fact this effect results in a perfectly *uniform* re-distribution of the probability.